# Performance impact of big field name and date type in Elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am investigating performance impact of long fields name in document 
example **created_timestamp_field1** vs **ctf1**

Q1) Which is preferred or best practice for field value and is there any performance / storage benefit?

Also is there any impact of storing date as long or in some format 
example **0000** vs **1 Jan 1970 00:00:00**.
date is eventually converted in long so not sure there is any impact of it in performance or storage
Q2) Is there any impact of using any of the above date value?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know the answer to this. JSON docs are hashtables though, so I wouldn't have thought this would matter much in terms of performance and storage. HOWEVER you will have more network traffic.
2. Use the date `type: date` in your mapping and you can define any format you want to send it in. They will all be converted to elasticsearch's date format anyway. If you use the date format you can do date math (e.g. `range:{ posted_date: now-1w }` to get docs in the last week). [Have a read of the es docs on mapping, scroll down to the date section](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/).  You can find out [more about date formats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/) too!

**Example mapping**

```
"posted_date": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd"
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Just to add a comment to point 1. **Don't** name a field so short that reading the name doesn't tell you what it is for. "ctf1" means nothing to anyone who doesn't know what it is already, "created_timestamp_field1" does, so out of those two, I would **strongly** prefer the latter, unless you **never** work with anyone else and you **never** forget what it means.